# Test on remove function

Tags: python, unit-testing

let's say I want to create a 'utils' package with several functions
working on files and folders. I want to do it once properly so I can use
them in all my personal projects without feeling to re invent the wheel
each time.
I also want to learn 2 items by the way:

- exception handling, already read a lot about EAFP vs LBYL, I think       the following function suits well to EAFP.
- unit tests with pytest tool, it seems simple enough to start with.

My function is:

```py
def removeanything(src):
    """
    remove files or folders
    """
    try:
        os.remove(src)
        print('File is removed')
    except IsADirectoryError:
        shutil.rmtree(src)
        print('Folder is removed')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('File/folder is not existing')
    except PermissionError:
        print('Not allowed to suppress this file')
```

Do you have any comment to do regarding my exception handling? Did I forget one or more exceptions?

To go ahead, I have written this test function for pytest:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import utils
#import pytest

def test_removeanything(tmp_path):
    d = tmp_path / '.tmp_dir'
    d.mkdir()
    f = d / '.tmp_file'
    f.touch()

    # Test permission
    d.chmod(mode=0o555)
    utils.removeanything(f)
    assert Path.exists(f)

    # Test file deletion
    d.chmod(mode=0o777)
    utils.removeanything(f)
    assert not Path.exists(f)

    # Test folder deletion
    utils.removeanything(d)
    assert not Path.exists(d)
```

As I am pretty newbie at testing, I would like to know if I include all reasonable things to assert for my function? Are there other way to do it more properly?
Is there a way to assert if expected error has been indeed raised by my function?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a general comment: I wouldn't make a function to remove files or directories, it may be dangerous. You can separate your function in two (or pass a flag) and make sure you will remove a file or a directory separately. I'm telling you this because I already had this problem. I removed an entire directory with results that took days to complete just because I passed the wrong path to a function like this one. Of course this is up to you, others may disagree.

Comment: you can check the [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryDirectory) module to make a temporary directory

Comment: I have rolled back your latest edit. Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Doc comments:**

You can be more clear in the doc comment about what the function does:

- What is the input? (string, path)
- Does it return anything? (no)
- Does it throw exceptions? (yes, because `os.remove` and `shutil.rmtree` may throw)
- What is the state after calling the function? (file/folder has been removed, except if there was a permission error or another error)

**Exceptions:**

Someone who calls `removeanything("myfile")` may expect that `myfile` does not exist anymore after the function call. However, in case of a permission error, it still does exist. I think this is an exceptional situation, so I recommend that you do not catch the `PermissionError` and instead propagate it to the caller.

**Output:**

Currently, the function communicates via print statements. This means that callers of the function have no way of finding out what actually happened. You could add a return value that indicates whether a file, a directory, or nothing was removed. Then you may think about removing the print statement, or enabling/disabling it via function argument, because users may want to remove files silently.

**Tests:**

It may be useful to separate the single test `test_removeanything` into multiple tests `test_removeanything_deletes_file`, `test_removeanything_deletes_directory`, `test_removeanything_handles_permission_error`. This way, if a test fails, the test name gives you some more information about what went wrong.

Often, functions that remove directories require them to be non-empty. Therefore, it makes sense to test the removal of both empty and non-empty directories.

If you change `removeanything` so that the `PermissionError` propagates to the user, you can use `pytest.raises` to test whether the exception was raised correctly.

**Misc:**

I think the name `removeanything` can be more specific. After all, the function does not remove a CD from my CD drive ;)

Comment: Very detailed answer! Thanks, I will update my code this way, it sounds relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my code this way, using pytest.fixtures with temp file/folders provided by pytest.

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import utils
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def fd(tmp_path):
    d = tmp_path / '.tmp_dir'
    d.mkdir()
    f = d / '.tmp_file'
    f.touch()
    return f,d

# Test permission
def test_permissions(fd):
    with pytest.raises(PermissionError):
        f,d = fd
        d.chmod(mode=0o555)
        utils.removeanything(f)

# Test file deletion
def test_delete_file(fd):
    f,d = fd
    utils.removeanything(f)
    assert not Path.exists(f)

# Test non empty folder deletion
def test_delete_folder_nonempty(fd):
    f,d = fd
    utils.removeanything(d)
    assert not Path.exists(d)

# Test empty folder deletion
def test_delete_folder_empty(fd):
    f,d = fd
    f.unlink()
    utils.removeanything(d)
    assert not Path.exists(d)
```

I have added other tests taking into account possiblke empty directory. Regarding test_permissions, a context manager tracks if error is well raised.